# Ex command to put value of variable into terminal emulator?

Tags: terminal, variables, terminal-buffer, input-methods

Using a terminal emulator (with `:term`), I would like to insert the value of a variable at the terminal cursor.

In a normal text buffer, I could use `put =g:my_variable` or `exec ("normal! i" . g:my_variable)`. Neither of these seems to work with the terminal emulator, however. How can I send the contents of the variable `g:my_variable` to the job that is running in the terminal emulator?

Comment: `put =g:my_variable` does work with the terminal emulator in neovim, but not with Vim8 (we get `E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `:terminal`, you can put any register using (`<c-w> = ctrl w`):

```
<c-w>"{register}
```

In particular, to insert the contents of a variable you can use the expression register:

```
<c-w>"= g:variable <cr>
```

If you are writing a script, in vim's terminal you may use the function `term_sendkeys` to send the contents of a variable to the terminal.

```
call term_sendkeys(bufnr('%'), g:contents)
```

If contents contains a "\n" newline character, the command will additionally be executed in the shell.

Comment: Hi @Mass, thank you for your answer. Do you know how to do this using an ex-mode command? I am writing a vim script...

Comment: updated the answer.  note that neovim and vim differ but I'm not familiar with the former

Comment: For reference: the `term_sendkeys(...)` function works for vim, and the `put =...` method works for neovim. Neovim does not have a `term_sendkeys` function (as of this writing).